# Display name attribute won't work when use MetadataType

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, metadatatype, displayname-attribute

I'm Working with ASP.NET MVC 5, database first. But entities in the edmx file, I can't add attributes, as that file will be overwritten every time I update it with database changes. I used MetadataType but Display name attribute won't work

```cs
namespace TemplateSite.Mvc.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class ezlib_BienMuc
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public ezlib_BienMuc()
        {
            this.ezlib_bienMuc_tacGia = new HashSet<ezlib_bienMuc_tacGia>();
            this.ezlib_kiem_ke = new HashSet<ezlib_kiem_ke>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ten_khac { get; set; }
        public string ky_hieu { get; set; }
        public string ten_vtat { get; set; }
        public string dvt { get; set; }
        public string anh_bia { get; set; }
        public string noi_dung { get; set; }
        public string tt_trach_nhiem { get; set; }
        public string tu_khoa { get; set; }
        public string de_muc { get; set; }
        public int ma_ngon_ngu { get; set; }
        public string noi_xuat_ban { get; set; }
        public int nam_xuat_ban { get; set; }
        public int ma_nha_xb { get; set; }
        public int lan_xuat_ban { get; set; }
        public string tung_thu { get; set; }
        public int tap_so { get; set; }
        public int ma_cap_hoc { get; set; }
        public int ma_khoi_hoc { get; set; }
        public int ma_mon_hoc { get; set; }
        public int ma_linh_vuc { get; set; }
        public int ma_dinhdang { get; set; }
        public int ma_size { get; set; }
        public string minh_hoa { get; set; }
        public string tai_lieu_nghe_nhin { get; set; }
        public int so_trang { get; set; }
        public string ghi_chu { get; set; }
        public string ghi_chu0 { get; set; }
        public string ghi_chu1 { get; set; }
        public string ghi_chu2 { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> active { get; set; }
        public string so_isbn { get; set; }
        public int ma_ddc { get; set; }
        public System.Guid sysuser_id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> edit_date { get; set; }

        public virtual ezlib_dm_CapHoc ezlib_dm_CapHoc { get; set; }
        public virtual ezlib_dm_MaDDC ezlib_dm_MaDDC { get; set; }
        public virtual ezlib_dm_DinhDang ezlib_dm_DinhDang { get; set; }
        public virtual ezlib_dm_KhoiHoc ezlib_dm_KhoiHoc { get; set; }
        public virtual ezlib_dm_LinhVuc ezlib_dm_LinhVuc { get; set; }
        public virtual ezlib_dm_MonHoc ezlib_dm_MonHoc { get; set; }
        public virtual ezlib_dm_NgonNgu ezlib_dm_NgonNgu { get; set; }
        public virtual ezlib_nhap_an_pham ezlib_nhap_an_pham { get; set; }
        public virtual ezlib_dm_NXB ezlib_dm_NXB { get; set; }
        public virtual ezlib_dm_Size ezlib_dm_Size { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<ezlib_bienMuc_tacGia> ezlib_bienMuc_tacGia { get; set; }
        public virtual sysuser sysuser { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<ezlib_kiem_ke> ezlib_kiem_ke { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is the metadata

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using TemplateSite.Mvc.Classes;

namespace TemplateSite.Mvc.Models
{
    [MetadataType(typeof (BienMucMetaData))]
    public partial class ezlib_BienMuc
    {
    }

    public class BienMucMetaData
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Tên khác")]
        public string ten_khac { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Kí hiệu")]
        [ReadOnly(true)]
        public string ky_hieu { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Vui lòng nhập nhan đề mã hoá")]
        [Display(Name = "Mã hoá nhan đề (Tên viết tắt)")]
        public string ten_vtat { get; set; }

        public string dvt { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Tóm tắt nội dung (520$a)")]
        public string noi_dung { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Thông tin trách nhiệm (245$c)")]
        public string tt_trach_nhiem { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Từ khoá (653$a)")]

        public string tu_khoa { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Chủ đề - Đề mục (650$a)")]
        public string de_muc { get; set; }

        public int ma_ngon_ngu { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Nơi xuất bản (260$a)")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Vui lòng nhập nơi xuất bản")]
        public string noi_xuat_ban { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Năm xuất bản (260$b)")]
        [YearValidate(Minimum = 1900, ErrorMessage = "Năm xuất bản phải từ năm 1900 đến năm hiện tại")]
        public int nam_xuat_ban { get; set; }

        public int ma_nha_xb { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Lần xuất bản (250$a)")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Vui lòng nhập lần xuất bản")]
        [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Vui lòng nhập chính xác lần xuất bản")]
        public int lan_xuat_ban { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Tùng thư (490$a)")]
        public string tung_thu { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Thông tin tập (254$n)")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Vui lòng nhập thông tin tập")]
        [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Vui lòng nhập chính xác thông tin tập")]
        public int tap_so { get; set; }

        public int ma_cap_hoc { get; set; }
        public int ma_khoi_hoc { get; set; }
        public int ma_mon_hoc { get; set; }
        public int ma_linh_vuc { get; set; }
        public int ma_dinhdang { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Vui lòng nhập kích thước")]
        public int ma_size { get; set; }

        public string minh_hoa { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Tài liệu nghe nhìn kèm theo")]
        public string tai_lieu_nghe_nhin { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Số trang (500$a)")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Vui lòng nhập số trang")]
        [Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Vui lòng nhập chính xác số trang")]
        public int so_trang { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Ghi chú")]
        public string ghi_chu { get; set; }

        public string ghi_chu0 { get; set; }
        public string ghi_chu1 { get; set; }
        public string ghi_chu2 { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Sử dụng")]
        public bool active { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Số ISBN (020$a)")]
        public string so_isbn { get; set; }

        public int ma_ddc { get; set; }
        public System.Guid sysuser_id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> edit_date { get; set; }
        public virtual ezlib_dm_CapHoc ezlib_dm_CapHoc { get; set; }
        public virtual ezlib_dm_MaDDC ezlib_dm_MaDDC { get; set; }
        public virtual ezlib_dm_DinhDang ezlib_dm_DinhDang { get; set; }
        public virtual ezlib_dm_KhoiHoc ezlib_dm_KhoiHoc { get; set; }
        public virtual ezlib_dm_LinhVuc ezlib_dm_LinhVuc { get; set; }
        public virtual ezlib_dm_MonHoc ezlib_dm_MonHoc { get; set; }
        public virtual ezlib_dm_NgonNgu ezlib_dm_NgonNgu { get; set; }
        public virtual ezlib_nhap_an_pham ezlib_nhap_an_pham { get; set; }
        public virtual ezlib_dm_NXB ezlib_dm_NXB { get; set; }
        public virtual ezlib_dm_Size ezlib_dm_Size { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage",
            "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<ezlib_bienMuc_tacGia> ezlib_bienMuc_tacGia { get; set; }

        public virtual sysuser sysuser { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage",
            "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<ezlib_kiem_ke> ezlib_kiem_ke { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and here is the view

```
        <ul class="form">
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ten_khac, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-21"})
                <div class="input">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ten_khac, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ten_khac, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Anyone know the problem please help me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I try codes you posted and that just work completely fine here is what i got rendered

```
<ul class="form">
   <li>
      <label class="control-label col-md-21" for="ten_khac">Tên khác</label>
            <div class="input">
                <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="ten_khac" name="ten_khac" type="text" value="">
                <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="ten_khac" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

i  think your problem is some thing else

Comment: Thanks for checking it, look like that my project has some problems. I created new controller and get error 404 when access it :(